# EB: Trigger container commands / deploy scripts on configuration change

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions, papertrail-app

I am running my web server on Elastic Beanstalk, and using Papertrail for logging. I am using the [official .ebextensions script](https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/blob/master/examples/remote_syslog.ebextensions.config) to get papertrail set up during deployment, but I have a problem. I use environment variables as part of my hostname used as the sender when remote_syslog uploads logs to papertrail, and while this works fine during deployment, when the `01_set_logger_hostname` container command is triggered, I run into problems whenever I change environment variables by modifying the environment's configuration, since it seems an `eb config` call will only restart the application server, not run any of the scripts run during deployment, including the ebextensions container commands.

```
"/tmp/set-logger-hostname.sh":
    mode: "00555"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      logger_config="/etc/log_files.yml"
      appname=`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`
      instid=`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
      myhostname=${SOME_VARIABLE}_${appname}_${instid}

      if [ -f $logger_config ]; then
        # Sub the hostname
        sed "s/hostname:.*/hostname: $myhostname/" -i $logger_config       
      fi
```

As you can see, since my hostname depends on `${SOME_VARIABLE}`, I need to refresh the hostname whenever `${SOME_VARIABLE}` is modified following `eb config`.

Is there a way to trigger a script to be run whenever an `eb config` command is run, so that I can not only restart my web application but also reconfigure and restart `remote_syslog` with the updated hostname?

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible on AWS Linux 2 based environments with [Configuration deployment platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

For example, you can make a shell script `.platform/confighooks/predeploy/predeploy.sh` that will run on all configuration changes.  Make sure that you make this file executable according to git, or Elastic Beanstalk will give you a permission denied error.

Comment: I had a similar issue as OP pulling env variables into a Django app. I moved the relevant code to a hook in `.platform/hooks/prebuild/env.sh` and it now runs on AWS console config changes. I chose prebuild because it runs right after download and extraction of the app which was the ideal time for my use case.