# Dynamic Procfile in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, procfile

I want to have a custom Procfile that is only used for some environments of my application but not all of them.  The point of an application is to deploy the same codebase, and I don't want to have perpetually different code branches just to maintain a different Procfile.

How do I have a Procfile be conditionally applied to some environments based on an environment variable (which I can then set differently on different environments)?

Just to give a concrete example of this, let's say I want DataDog to only be included on some of my environments but not all of them.  DataDog requires a custom Procfile, where you prepend `ddtrace-run` to the actual command you want to run.  So I want some of my environments to be running `ddtrace-run gunicorn ...` and I want others to just be running `gunicorn ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to make a Procfile that has a conditional bash command, such as `test $ENV_VAR && command_a || command_b`.  To do this in a Procfile using the DataDog example would look like this:

```
web: test $DD_ENABLED && ddtrace-run gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 2 --threads 15 config.wsgi:application || gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 2 --threads 15 config.wsgi:application
```

While you can create a Procfile with a `container_command`, this is dangerous to do because Elastic Beanstalk will delete it on config changes: [Elastic Beanstalk deleting generated files on config changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70386134/2800876)

Comment: Does this actually work for you @zags? I came up with the same approach recently, but without using test (just used `[[ $DD_ENABLED=1 ]]`), both `[[ ]]` and `test ` will give you exit status 1 I think and this will break the deployment and/or execution of Procfile commands in EB

Comment: You may need to add explicit `|| return 0` at the end of the command to avoid breaking the whole deployment process

Comment: It won't work with return or exit 0 anyway, AWS EB checks the pid of the started named process from Procfile, so it'll result in
```
[WARN] Failed to read file /var/pids/worker.pid, retry attempt: 1
```

Comment: @januszm Yes, this worked for me (that's why I posted it as an answer).  I have used this successfully in a number of eb enviornments.  Try using the exact syntax in my answer